# What are the voltage and current of the capacitor at t>0 in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor

[image: The switch was open for a long time t<0 and it closes at t=0. What are the voltage and current of the capacitor at t>0 in this circuit? If possible provide those at t<0 and t=0 as well (explanation of the process much appreciated) Sorry for being so demanding and thanks a lot!]
The switch was open for a long time t<0 and it closes at t=0. What are the voltage and current of the capacitor at t>0 in this circuit? If possible provide those at t<0 and t=0 as well (explanation of the process much appreciated) Sorry for being so demanding and thanks a lot!

Comment: Please redraw using the built in schematic editor. My eyes hurt.

Comment: @Brian Drummond Sorry for that. I'm still new to this site. Mind telling me where to find that?

Comment: @HRS2679 when you edit your question, there is a schematic symbol in the toolbar (right next to the add image button).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your voltage source in 10V (hard to see)...

Capacitor voltage is 0V at t=0
Capacitor current is 10V / (26.67Ohm) * (20Ohm / 30Ohm) = 0.25 A at t=0

The values will reach a steady state at t>>0 with

Capacitor voltage = 5V and current = 0A

**EDIT:**
The capacitor is at 0V and can be modelled as a short circuit at the time t=0
The parallel resistance of R3 and R5 is 6.67Ohm
The total circuit resistance at t=0 is 10+10+6.77=26.67 Ohm
Total current is 10/26.67 A
The current through the capacitor branch is 2/3 of the total because the resistance is in the ratio 1:2

At t>>0 the capacitor has completed charging and will have current flow of 0A.
The voltage across it will be the save as the voltage on R5.  The voltage ratio will be determined by R1, R2 and R5 and be half of the battery voltage, the capacitor resistor does not take part as current no longer flows through it.

If you use the site schematic editor which is available in the edit box toolbar you can also do basic simulation of the circuit if you wish and see the asymptotic waveforms for the voltages and currents.  If you have access to a lab with the components and a scope you can wire it up and test it, that is the most rewarding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering and yes it is 10V. Would you mind explaining how you got these results?